# Can I create two different GET requests from the same address in the server

Tags: javascript, express, get, localserver

I want to get two different return values from the same address in the sever - one for all the data after some filtering and one for the length of the data before filtering, but I don't need them at the same time. Is it possible to create two different GET request for some address and get a different information by specifying which data I want?

This how I'm doing it now:

```
app.get('/api/orders', (req, res) => {
    const page = <number>(req.query.page || 1);
    const search = <string>(req.query.search || "");
    const filter = <string>(req.query.filter || "order");
    let length = allOrders.length;
    let orders: any[];

    let counter = 0;
    allOrders.map((order) => {
        if (order.fulfillmentStatus === 'not-fulfilled') {
            counter += 1;
        }
    })

    if (search !== "") {

        if (filter === "item") {
            orders = allOrders.filter((order) => order.items.filter((item: {id: string, quantity: number}) =>
            products[item.id].name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())).length != 0);
        }
        else {
            orders = allOrders.filter((order) =>
                (order.customer.name.toLowerCase() + order.id).includes(search.toLowerCase()));
        }
        length = orders.length;
        orders = orders.slice((page - 1) * PAGE_SIZE, page * PAGE_SIZE);
    }
    else {
        orders = allOrders.slice((page - 1) * PAGE_SIZE, page * PAGE_SIZE);
    }
    res.send({orders, length, counter});
});
```

But I want to be able to get the `counter` without calculating the other two values (`orders` and `length`)

Comment: you simply need to add some new `if` statements to check which fields are needed (say from `query` string) and adjust the `res.send()` accordingly.

Comment: This is what I'm doing for now, but I have to specify what is the return value's type, and with this method I'm getting two different data types. @Tibebes.M